# Is iterate with nested foreach in scala functional?

Tags: scala, loops, functional-programming, structure, scala-collections

I have a

```
finals = Set[(String, String)]
```

and an

```
init = Array[(String, String), String]
```

What I am trying to do is if a `(String, String)` of the array **init**,  is equal to a tuple of the **finals** set, add it in a `Map[(String, String), String]`.

For example **finals** is:

```
Set[(m1, c1), (m2, c1)]
```

and **init** is:

```
Array[[(m1, c1), n], [(m2, c2), l], (m2, c1), k]]
```

The result would be:

```
Map[((m1, c1), n), ((m2, c1), k)]
```

My question is if nested `foreach` are correct in scala? As far as i wrote the code for iterating both of the structures simultaneously, there was no error and it worked, but i don't know if it is a functional way.

My code is:

```
init.foreach(i => {
 finals.foreach(j => {
  if (i._1.equals(j))
   { counts += (i._1 -> i._2) }
  })
 })
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `counts +=` is definitely not purely functional.

Comment: It's a closure, right?

Comment: Closure's are functional, shared mutable state is not.

Comment: Also, _Scala_ `Array`s can only have a single type parameter, so your definition of an `Array[(String, String), String]` (an `Array` of a `(String, String)` tuple and a `String`) is 1 type argument too many. Can you clarify?

Comment: So, it would be ok if i changed the Map to immutable and the Array to Set?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way of writing this code

```
counts = init.filter(e => finals.contains(e._1)).toMap
```

#### Explanation

The best way to think about this sort of problem is to look at the basic operations that you are performing and work out the equivalent operation in Scala.

The main operation you require is to *select specific elements of a collection* called `init`, and the Scala operation for that is `filter`.

The test you are applying is to see if the first tuple *is in another collection*, and the Scala operation for that is `contains`.

Finally, you want to *convert a collection of tuples into a `Map`*, and the Scala operation for that is `toMap`.

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` can be functional, but `counts += ...` is not - as a side-effect, it mutates the `counts` data structure.

Here's a rather longer answer that results in a one-liner, but I'm trying to explain the thought process:

When struggling to come up with a functional way of writing the code, I often find it helpful to think about how I might for example use...

- recursion
- more advanced operations (map, flatMap, reduce, filter, fold, ...)

In this case, if you e.g. think about how you might do a `map`, you could rephrase this:

> What I am trying to do is if a (String, String) of the array finals, is equal to a tuple of the init set, add it in a Map[(String, String), String].

(I assume you accidentally swapped finals/init in your question but had them the right way round in the code bit)

as:

What I'm trying to do is map over the `(String, String)` items in the array `finals`, and if one of them is in `init`, return the found item. The returned value is stored in `counts`.

However, in this case, that doesn't quite get you what you want - `map` requires you to return exactly 1 item for each item you map over, so you need to change to `flatMap` to avoid that constraint.

```
val finals: Set[(String, String)] = Set(("m1", "c1"), ("m2", "c1"))

val init: Array[((String, String), String)] = Array((("m1", "c1"), "n"), (("m2", "c2"), "l"), (("m2", "c1"), "k"))

val counts = finals.flatMap( finals_item => init.filter(_._1 == finals_item))
/*
Set[((String, String), String)] = Set(
  (("m1", "c1"), "n"),
  (("m2", "c1"), "k")
)
*/
```

Then you just add `.toMap`:

```
finals.flatMap( finals_item => init.filter(_._1 == finals_item)).toMap
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. It helped me to grasp a new rule for map that I didn't know I was following haha

Answer (score 0):

Here is a functional way of using it using `collect`

```
scala> val x=Set(("m1", "c1"), ("m2", "c1"))
//x: scala.collection.immutable.Set[(String, String)] = Set((m1,c1), (m2,c1))

scala> val y = Array((("m1", "c1"), "n"), (("m2", "c2"), "l"), (("m2", "c1"), "k"))

//y: Array[((String, String), String)] = Array(((m1,c1),n), ((m2,c2),l), ((m2,c1),k))

scala> y.collect{
        case e if x.filter(p=> p._1 == e._1._1 && p._2 == e._1._2).size>0 => e 
     }
//res3: Array[((String, String), String)] = Array(((m1,c1),n), ((m2,c1),k))
```